# Binary search for an element less than or equal to a given

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, binary-search

is there a way to quickly find a element that is equal or less than the given in set container, using the "algorithm" library? I have an algorithm that I wrote, but I think that it will be better and more convenient with the library.

Comment: prev of [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) / [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) with reverse_iterator?

Comment: You can also do it on the set itself: `std::prev(my_set.upper_bound(key), 1);` (also needs bounds checking in case `upper_bound()` returns the first element in the set.)

Comment: Be careful how you word your requirements. You probably meant "find **the largest** element that is equal or less than the given". If you really meant just **an** element then you just have to look at the first element in the set. If any element of the set is smaller than the given, then the smallest element (the first) is. If the first element is larger than the given, then no element of the set is less than or equal to the given.

Comment: @Dave sets are sorted containers.